# SVN: '0x00400103: Compare with Revision' operation finished with error, why?

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am working with Eclipse Neon CDT and till now I could make use of my SVN server to compare revision, however since I update to the lates available version of the plugin, currently I work with these versions

```
>   Subversive SVN
> Connectors    6.0.1.I20160627-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group   Polarion
> Software
>     Subversive SVN Team Provider  4.0.3.I20161129-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group  Eclipse.org
> Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions
> (Optional)    4.0.0.I20160226-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.resource.ignore.rules.jdt.feature.group    Eclipse.org
> Subversive SVN Team Provider Localization
> (Optional)    4.0.0.I20160226-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.nl1.feature.group  Eclipse.org
```

I get this error

```
SVN: '0x00400103: Compare with Revision' operation finished with error: Path is not an immediate child of the specified directory?
```

Have someone experienced this issue? What can I do?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may have better luck with https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/support.php

Comment: I have asked that on that forum too https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1084220/

Comment: This has also been reported as a bug in eclipses bug tracker: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509424
Seems to be a pretty recent problem, since i can't find much on the internet.

Comment: @ScriptKiddy yes I think so, I couldn't find much either

Comment: Anyways, i have talked to my colleagues, some of them use subclipse and some use subversive, it seems to be working fine with subclipse, so you might use that instead (i gonna do the same), should be no big difference.